# Spyder console not working after installing into spyder-env using Miniconda after a fresh Ubuntu Studio install

Tags: linux, ipython, spyder, miniconda

[The errors.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdRRb.png)

I don't know what's going on. I want to install conda-forge Spyder in a dedicated environment, [per the installation instructions](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/installation.html), and it boots up just fine, but the console is jacked up. I'm not sure how to proceed. Spyder-kernels is installed, fwiw. iPython and QTConsole start up just fine from my terminal in the envrironment too. The console just seems to be messed in Spyder itself.

Just installed Ubuntu Studio 23.10. I had this working on Pop OS with the full Anaconda install and a Spyder install in the base envrionment, but I want to do this the right way with an install in "spyder-env" using Miniconda.

I'm still wrapping my head around all this conda/virtual environment stuff, so please let me know if there's some more info you need.

I'm confused about the Permission error... Is that all this is?

I expected the console to work! I've gone by the book on all my installations (Ubuntu Studio, Miniconda, Spyder).

Comment: Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask]. Also don't make us go through a lengthy document that you said you followed... probably you didn't, and we need to know what exactly you did, not what you were supposed to do. At this point it's just guesswork. That said: Check your conda activation script, is it executable, owned by the same user as the one that gets the error? Did you make the environment as another use, maybe root, with `sudo` or such? Did you copy the environment from another machine without changing the owner user?